# Parsing from a list in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-parsing

I currently have a db table that list an employee and their rights like so:

```
User          Groups
Johnson       DB~LB~AP
Doe           DB~PLA
```

I need a parsing function that is able to list out all users and all associated groups, like so:

```
User          Groups
Johnson       DB
Johnson       LB
Johnson       AP
Doe           DB
Doe           PLA
```

I was able to find this awesome parsing function (http://sqlfool.com/2011/05/string-parsing-function/), but I'm unable to run this for a list of users. I can run the parsing function for one user at a time but am stumped on how I can run a list of users through this function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That parser has two pretty bit performance problems. It is using a recursive cte which is not ideal. The bigger issue is that it is a mult-statement table valued function which will often have worse performance than a scalar function. Take a look at this article for several better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use that function like this:

```
select t.user, g.grp
from t cross apply
     dbo.dba_parseString_udf(t.groups, '~') g(grp);
```

You do need to define the function in the dbo schema in your current database.

Comment: I might be missing something, but what is the g(grp) doing?

Comment: By the way, thank you! I was able to manipulate this query to do exactly what I needed, but I am still unsure what purpose the g(grp) is serving.

Comment: @user2572833 Defines an alias for the table returned, and specifies a column name for the one column in that table.

Comment: Perfect! Turns out this is exactly what I needed. Thank you for taking the time to respond. It's greatly appreciated!